# Flutter Listview - Subtitle and DateDiff problem

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, listview, datediff

i need your help :)
I think this is not working... but i mean i can do it with an extra page like a "detailpage" and show the data. Well here is my issue

i have the main screen with a listview.Builder for all my entries.
it just shows an icon, the title(name) and a Date (the Date is in the future that i can define in the add screen)

ok now my problem. i need a Datediff. i dont want to show the future Date (endTime), i want the differnce days between today and the future Date

```
child: ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage:
      AssetImage('asset/veggi.png'), ),
      title: Text(vegetableEntry.items[index].title),
      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(vegetableDetailScreen.routeName,
      arguments: vegetableEntry.items[index].id),
      subtitle:  Text(vegetableEntry.items[index].endTime.difference(dateNow2).inDays),
```

somtehing like:

```
that i get on my subtitle smth like: Icon/ Title(name) /DaysLeft: 29 (checks everytime on open?)
```

i'm getting the error:
The method 'difference' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'difference'.

i know i can fix it in the DetailScreen with

```
    DateTime startDate = _pickedStartDate;
    DateTime endDate = _pickedEndDate;
    final daysLeft = endDate.difference(startDate).inDays;
    print(daysLeft);
```

but i dont think this is possible in the Listview.builder ?

i hope this is understandable and someone can help me

best regards,
and a happy day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually is possible in `ListView.builder`. Just do the work in the `builder` function before you return the `ListTile`. You can't use `(context, index) =>`. You'll have to use `(context, index) {}`.

You can also convert the `Timestamp` `String` into a `DateTime` inline like so

```
subtitle:  Text(DateTime.parse(vegetableEntry.items[index].endTime).difference(dateNow2).inDays.toString(),
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!! the inline is exactly what i had needed : D